# When does Hibernate create a new entry from a FK to a non-PK column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

suppose I have:

```
-- table_1 -------------------  
|id      | property_x | data |
------------------------------

-- table_2 ------------------------
|id      | property_x | moar_data |
-----------------------------------
```

And that `table_1` has a FK from `property_x` to `table_2.property_x`
(why not `table_2.id`? IDK, this project was already like this :( )

The HBMs look like this:

```xml
<!-- Table 1 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example">
    <class name="Table1" table="table_1">
        <id column="id" type="integer" name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one class="Table2" fetch="join" name="table2" not-null="false">
            <column name="property_x" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```xml
<!-- Table 2 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example">
    <class name="Table2" table="table_2">
        <id column="id" type="integer" name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property column="property_x" name="propertyX" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The thing is that I want to save an object `Table1` using `session.save(objTable1)`, without creating a new Table2 entry in the DB, and without loading it either. 
I have done this in the past by creating a new object, and only setting the primary key values, leaving everything else blank, and not letting it update the `Table2` table, but this is not the PK >_<.

Now, suppose I have in `table_2` an entry `with id=5`, `property_x="EX"`. When I do the following...

```java
// example method
public void saveSomething(Sessions sess) {
    Table1 table1 = new Table1();
    Table2 table2 = new Table2();

    table2.setPropertyX("EX");
    table1.setTable2(table2);

    sess.save(table1);
}
```

... it creates a new entry, I'm guessing it's because the PK (id) for `Table2` is not set.

My question is, how does hibernate decide to create a new entry in the DB from a FK object?, and is there a way to avoid that on the HBM files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the cascade anotation, if you dont want table 2 to be created in the db, dont set it as a child, but if you want table 2 to be updated, you need the table 2 id.

Alternatively, you can set cascade="none" in the hbm of table 1 or cascade="update", but table 2 still wont be updated without the id.

Comment: So the ideal way would be to load the Table2 object first, or to create an HQL statement?

Comment: yeah, you should load table2 using the table1 forean key and then perform the update.

Comment: You are right, It's either that or make the HQL statement on your own, I'll try this and hope it's not slow (having to load an object I won't really use :s) and if that's acceptable, I'll use that, else I'll build the queries.